# How to convert a ruby integer into a symbol

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby array like this

```
q_id = [1,2,3,4,5,...,100]
```

I want to iterate through the array and convert into a hash like this

```
{
  :1 => { #some hash} ,  
  :2 => { #another hash},
  ...
  :100 => {#yet another hash}
}
```

What is the shortest and most elegant way to accomplish this?

[EDIT : the to_s.to_sym while being handy is not how I want it. Apologies for not mentioning it earlier.]

Comment: I don't think that's legal.  Try to type `:1` in `irb` and you'll get a syntax error.

Comment: As mentioned below, :1 is not valid.  The best you can get is :"1".  I'm not sure why this matters so much, as the quotes are not really "part" of the symbol .. but it's how it must be defined for parsing/grammar reasons.

Comment: Perhaps you should show us what you are really trying to accomplish. Why do you feel that you need numbers-as-symbols for the keys of your Hash? How are you later going to index the hash, or if you iterate it what will you be doing with the keys?

Comment: Well I was trying to convert the keys of the following hash into indexable integers and thought :"22" did not look totally clean or elegant enough.

"qs"=>{"22"=>["56", "57"], "1"=>["1", "2", "13", "14"], "2"=>["3", "4", "5"]}

My bad that I forgot the basic meaning of a symbol in ruby and that its a static representation of a string - the javascript effect basically (as you rightly guessed)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For creating a symbol, either of these work:

```
42.to_s.to_sym
:"#{42}"
```

The `#inspect` representation of these shows `:"42"` only because `:42` is not a valid Symbol literal. Rest assured that the double-quotes are not part of the symbol itself.

To create a hash, there is no reason to convert the keys to symbols, however. You should simply do this:

```
q_id = (1..100).to_a
my_hash_indexed_by_value = {}
q_id.each{ |val| my_hash_indexed_by_value[val] = {} }
```

Or this:

```
my_hash = Hash[ *q_id.map{ |v| [v,{}] }.flatten ]
```

Or this:

```
# Every time a previously-absent key is indexed, assign and return a new hash
my_hash = Hash.new{ |h,val| h[val] = {} }
```

With all of these you can then index your hash directly with an integer and get a unique hash back, e.g.

```
my_hash[42][:foo] = "bar"
```

Unlike JavaScript, where every key to an object must be a string, Hashes in Ruby accept *any* object as the key.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Explaination!!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm well, yes; I was assuming a variable would be used in place of `42`, but I suppose that might not be clear to newcomers. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

Actually "symbol numbers" aren't a thing in Ruby (try to call the `to_sym` method on a number). The benefit of using symbols in a hash is about performance, since they always have the same `object_id` (try to call `object_id` on strings, booleans, numbers, and symbols).

Numbers are immediate value and, like Symbol objects, they always have the same object_id.

Anyway, using the new hash syntax implies using symbols as keys, but you can always use the old good "hash rocket" syntax

`awesome_hash = { 1 => "hello", 2 => "my friend" }`

Read about immediate values here:

https://books.google.de/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=immediate+values+singleton+method&source=bl&ots=fIFlAe8xjy&sig=j7WgTA1Cft0WrHwq40YdTA50wk0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=0kHSUKCVB-bW0gHRxoHQAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 3):

To translate an integer into a symbol, use `to_s.to_sym` .. e.g.,:

```
1.to_s.to_sym
```

Note that a symbol is more related to a string than an integer.  It may not be as useful for things like sorting anymore.

Comment: Yes, as Andy mentioned, I am looking at a way to convert it to :1 and not :"1" . Already ruled out the direct to_sym method

Comment: You can't have a symbol like :1.  A symbol is pretty much a String with some special properties.

Comment: @papdel There is no such Symbol as `:1`; `:"1"` is the way you describe a symbol whose string representation is `1`; the quotes are not part of the symbol length. `:"7".length #=> 1` You don't want a symbol key, you want a numeric key. See my answer.

Comment: Agree with @Phrogz.  I think you really do want to stick with a numeric key.

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a hard-coded constant numeric symbol, there's a simpler way:

```
:'99'
```

This produces the same results as the more complex methods in other answers:

```
irb(main):001:0> :'99'
=> :"99"
irb(main):002:0> :"#{99}"
=> :"99"
irb(main):003:0> 99.to_s.to_sym
=> :"99"
```

Of course, this will not work if you're dynamically creating a symbol from a variable, in which case one of the other two approaches is required.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, :1 is not a valid symbol. Here's one way to do what you're wanting, but with the keys as strings:

```
Hash[a.collect{|n| [n.to_s, {}] }]
```

Answer (score 1):

An array of the objects you want in your hash would be so much easier to use, wouldn't it? Even a hash of integers would work pretty well, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

u can use
1.to_s.to_sym

but this will make symbols like :"1"

Answer (score 0):

You can make symbolic keys with `Hash[]`:

```rb
a = Hash[(1..100).map{ |x| ["#{x}".to_sym, {}] }]
```

Check type of hash keys:

```rb
puts a.keys.map(&:class)

=>
Symbol
...
Symbol
Symbol
```

Comment: Please explain your answer as well. Adding just code doesnt help.